# graphx graph.apply constructor method - edge partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a weighted graph with ~340k vertices and ~772k edges. I build an edge and vertices RDD from a file on HDFS.

`val verticesRDD : RDD[(VertexId, Long)]`

`val edgesRDD : RDD[Edge[Double]]`

From these RDDs I create a graph using the `.apply` method.

`val my_graph: Graph[(Long),Double] = Graph.apply(verticesRDD, edgesRDD)`

I then compute a shortest path algorithm for a range of inputs. This works well on a single node implementation. However, when I run in cluster mode with multiple nodes, I am not seeing a speed up or hardware utilisation.

Reading the documentation, I see that "`GraphX provides several ways of building a graph from a collection of vertices and edges in an RDD or on disk. None of the graph builders repartitions the graph’s edges by default; instead, edges are left in their default partitions (such as their original blocks in HDFS).`"

Thus, it makes sense that I am not seeing a speed up as the edges are left in their original default partition, on HDFS.

I then tried the `partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut)` method but this obviously does not help with repartitioning edges.

I found there is a `minEdgePartitions` argument for constructing a graph using the `fromEdgeTuples` method.

How do I partition edges with the `graph.apply` constructor method?

Comment: Have you already tried **partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.EdgePartition2D)**? Edges are assigned to the partitions using both the source vertex and the destination vertex.

Comment: All possible partitioning strategies can be found in the following link: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.PartitionStrategy$

Answer (score 0):

The `minEdgePartitions` parameter used by `fromEdgeTuples` is passed to its RDD builder, so here what you should do to get the same result (partitioned edges) is to first build a partitioned edgeRDD than pass it to `graph.apply`.

```
val parts = 100
val edgesRDD : RDD[Edge[Double]] = sc.textFile[Edge[Double]]]("/path/to/file", 
                                        minPartitions = parts)
val verticesRDD : RDD[(VertexId, Long)]
val my_graph: Graph[(Long),Double] = Graph.apply(verticesRDD, edgesRDD)
```